# Do not reset variable in class after refresh

Tags: php, html

It is possible to keep a variable after a refresh?
Sessions don't work, because it's on the server side.

I mean, I have a class with an array `var`.
I would like to add a string to the array in another php site (`includes "CLASS"`), but when I refresh the site, the array is empty.

Comment: Why doesn't sessions work ? PHP is also on the "server site"

Answer (score 0):

Everything is run through again, so it gets lost.

Perhaps you want to store it in `$_SESSION`? Sessions work on the server side.

You could also write data to a file and read it every time.